# the third argument of urllib.urlretrieve is a function and the total size of the file is -1

Tags: python, web

The argument of urllib.urlretrieve is a function. It has three arguments:a count of blocks transferred so far, a block size in bytes, and the total size of the file,but the total size of the file is return -1,for example:

```
def reportbook(a,b,c):
    print "%.2f%%" % (100*a*b/c)
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.baidu.com","files/baidu.html",reportbook)
```

In the example,reportbook is the function,c is the the total size of the file.
c return -1,but it should not return -1.

It is not correct? but in other example it seems to be right,when

`urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.python.org","files/baidu.html",reportbook)`

c returns the actual total size of the page:549

Why？

Comment: Your call to reportbook doesn't have any input arguments for the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask **questions** and other readers attempt to **answer** them. SO is not a problem-and-resolution site, nor is it a discussion forum. Your post is lacking a key element: a question. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: @heinst reportbook is the third argument, it  will be called once on establishment of the network connection and once after each block read thereafter.So it automatically created by the urlretrieve.

Comment: "The third argument may be -1 on older FTP servers which do not return a file size in response to a retrieval request."
Perhaps also for HTTP servers that don't tell the file size. And it's report**hook**, not book :)

Comment: @Jasper Thank you for reminding.The code is correct,but the python document is reporthook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baidu.com does not supply a `Content-Length` header. Python.org does. If the `Content-Length` header is missing, then -1 is passed as the third argument to the report hook.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code, baidu.com just doesn't tell you how much data it will send. Here's an example `wget` session:

```
$ wget "http://www.baidu.com"
--2014-07-30 16:29:26--  http://www.baidu.com/
Resolving www.baidu.com (www.baidu.com)... 220.181.111.188, 220.181.112.244
Connecting to www.baidu.com (www.baidu.com)|220.181.111.188|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

You should therefore handle the special case `c == -1` separately.